# Using nodeJS and phantomJS to return network requests and responses, only working in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to replicate the phantomJS [netlog.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/netlog.js) functionality, only in nodeJS. I'm using the [phantomjs-node module](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) as a bridge.

Normally, this would be run headlessly in the command line using `phantomjs netlog.js http://www.google.com/`. It would return a lot of json containing all network requests and responses.

What I'm doing here is trying to run the code from `netlog.js` inside of a page created using the `phantomjs-node` module (ignoring the line `var page = require('webpage').create()` from `netlog.js`.

While the code doesn't break, I'm not getting the return of the json. What's wrong here? Do I need to somehow pipe the page request?

In `app.js`:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

siteUrl = "http://www.google.com/"
phantom.create(function (ph) {
    ph.createPage(function (page) {
        var system = require('system'),
        address;
        page.open(siteUrl, function (status) {
        // console.log("opened " + siteUrl +"\n",status+"\n");

            page.evaluate(function () { 
                if (system.args.length === 1) {
                    console.log('Usage: netlog.js <some URL>');
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                console.log(system.args[1])
                    address = system.args[1];

                    page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
                        console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
                    };

                    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
                        console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
                    };

                    page.open(address, function (status) {
                        if (status !== 'success') {
                            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
                        }
                        phantom.exit();
                    });
                }

            }, function finished(result) {

                ph.exit();            
            },thirdLayerLinks);

        });
    });
}, {
dnodeOpts: {
    weak: false
}
});
```

Comment: I pasted it exactly as it appears and functions in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake during copy-paste. There shouldn't be a `page.evaluate` call and only one `page.open` call. You took a little too much from the basic phantomjs-node code.

PhantomJS and Node.js have different runtimes and vastly different modules. There is no `phantom` reference. Additionally there is no `system` in node. You probably mean `process`.

Then the [docs](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) say the following:

> Callbacks can't be set directly, instead use `page.set('callbackName', callback)`

Fixed code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var address = "http://google.com/";
phantom.create(function (ph) {
    ph.createPage(function (page) {
        page.set("onResourceRequested", function (req) {
            console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
        });

        page.set("onResourceReceived", function (res) {
            console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
        });

        page.open(address, function (status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('FAIL to load the address');
            }
            ph.exit();
        });
    });
}, {
    dnodeOpts: {
        weak: false
    }
});
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`...just saying.

Comment: Nice. It's confusing with the `dnodeOpts`...Also, I'm logging `console.log(process.argv[1])` and it just gives me the location where the code is contained, which as the same as what system returned. I'm not sure why.

Comment: When I manually change this to `address = "http://google.com` it doesn't return anything.

Comment: `console.log(process.argv)` equals `['node','C:\...whatever...app.js']`

Comment: It just returns `undefined` for `console.log(process.argv[2])`

Comment: Fantastic!  No I'm not using the command line because there are too many links.

Comment: What exactly is the `page.set` doing that `onResourceRequested` wasn't?

Comment: The same thing, but it has to be done differently, because otherwise the bridge would lose control.